# We develop Bluetooth Low Energy on IOS 6 with Xcode 4.5.2. The apps downloaded to a IOS5 device can connect to BLE device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We develop Bluetooth Low Energy Apps as Central on IOS 6 SDK with Xcode 4.5.2.  The apps downloaded to a IOS5(IPad3) device can connect to BLE device without problem.  However if this apps is to download to a IOS 6 device it will have problem.  The apps can discover the BLE device(shown on the list) but when we click on to connect, it failed. We are using the latest IPod5.

Comment: You might need to provide a little more information here. What does the code look like for connecting to these devices? What kind of device are they? Are there any connection errors being reported by Core Bluetooth?

Comment: For people to help, you need to post a sample of your code and also the error you are getting on iOS 6.

Comment: we are using the temperature sensor sample code downloaded from apple

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the iOS 6 bug mentioned here: [iOS 6 UUID Problem](http://olesitune.mine.nu/blelogg/?p=221)

A way to quickly check would be to add an NSLog to check the peripheral name when discovering peripherals.

If peripheralName is Null, or if it crashes on CFUUIDCreateString you've found your problem. The only way that I've found to fix is to connect to the peripheral first [manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil] and then disconnect and reconnect. Once you've done that you should be able to use CFUUIDCreateString without problems.

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
   if (peripherals.count == 0)
   {
        [peripherals addObject: peripheral];
        NSString *peripheralName;
        peripheralName = [peripheral name];
        NSString *foundDevice = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, [peripheral UUID]));
        NSLog(@"Found %@", peripheralName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this sound strange, but also have terrible BLE issues with iPad3 iOS6. Namely Peripheral name does not reflect changes I introduce in micro-controller's software.

I have iPhone5 with iOS 6.1 beta 4 and iPhone 4s iOS 6.0. Both work flawlessly with my CC2540 projects.

Comment: Have your tried going to settings->general->reset->reset all settings ?  That will reset the bluetooth uuid cache.

Comment: @svaha Nope. I like my setting.